# How to make a video chat app web using SimpleWebRTC error

Tags: webrtc, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I was following a tutorial on Dzone however I completed the application but there were some errors.

https://dzone.com/articles/build-a-video-chat-service-with-javascript-webrtc

The first error is SimpleWebRtc is deprecated https://simplewebrtc.com/latest-v3.js

So since this link does not work anymore what do I do? Since I don't know how the functions work in the javascript section it's hard to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Head over to github and grab the file yourself: https://github.com/andyet/simplewebrtc

Comment: Thank you but if I'm not mistaken the open source simplewebrtc is now deprecated and now doesn't work...Deprecated
The open-source version of SimpleWebRTC has been deprecated. This repository will remain as-is but is no longer actively maintained. You can find the old website in the gh-pages branch. Read more about the "new" SimpleWebRTC (which is an entirely different thing) on https://simplewebrtc.com